# Xcode not allowing to copy files to bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am having problem in copying files to Xcode bundle.
I have some files in my bundle and i am trashing them and copy new same named one from another project.
But regularly Xcode giving error as : **Multiple errors occurred while copying the files.**
I have done much RND but no solution.
Can anybody help me out.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: What are the exact errors you are getting? And when are you copying files into the bundle exactly? Do you mean into the project?

Comment: yes in the project. Xcode showing alert **Multiple errors occurred while copying the files**

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: Xcode showing alert **Multiple errors occurred while copying the files**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you just deleted files from your project but one copy of each file is still in folder where your project is. Delete all red lines first if there is any. And see below steps -

1. Right Click on your project
2. Show in finder
3. Find your files and delete them
4. Now delete all red line files
5. **Command+shift+k** clean your project.
6. Now add new files.

Comment: I realize this is somewhat of an old post, but am adding here in case other people run into this issue. Here's what my issue was:

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post but am adding here in case others run into the same issue. I was working on a project where I utilized AFNetworking and performed the following steps:

1. I dragged and dropped the files into my project and asked **xCode 5** to make a copy of the same (rather than create a reference).
2. I needed to delete the folder/files I just imported and right clicked on the same in the file navigator in xCode and hit Delete - I did delete the folder/files in the manner laxonline describes above.
3. Attempted to re-add the AFNetworking library code back into my project and got the below message.

[image]

The fix here is to follow the steps in the accepted answer - i.e. To right click on your project in xCode, select Show in Finder and then delete the offending files/folders.

I upvoted the accepted answer but am also posting this as a separate answer so I can highlight that the above can occur even if you select the correct delete option. In my case, I discovered that while the AFNetworking files were no longer in the directory, an empty folder with said name still existed.

Answer (score 1):

While deleting the exicting files from Xcode. The Xcode4 asks you **"Do you want to permanently delete the file “fileName” from disk, or only remove the reference to it?"**

By default the alert selects "Remove Reference Only" 
Change it to Delete.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

while deleting files you must select move to trash option.
If you select Remove References then only the link to those files gets removed and you will have to manually delete those files from their location.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was related to garbage from previous builds. I've solved by removing all Derived data:

```
rm -f ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

First I've closed xcode; then removed those files; then restart xcode pointed to your project.